# Interpretation of limit for this sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, epsilon-delta

[image]

I know all the steps of how they worked the limit out, but I am having trouble interpreting its meaning. If I substituent 1 into my equation I get 3. And this is as close to $\sqrt5$ $\approx$ 2.23 as I can get. But even this feels a bit far. I mean why couldn't the limit be 2.5 or 2.99?

As an example, the value of  $\frac{sin(n)}{n}$ is very close to 0 for large values of n.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: There should be writing below the picture. My question is embedded in that.

Comment: Well, $f(3) \approx 2.33$ and the next term in the sequence is $2.238$. So I really don't know what you mean by "And this is as close to $\sqrt 5$ as I can get."

Comment: Ah my fault. I only tried f(1) and then really large values.

Comment: It is not monotonic so that was erroneous of me to do.

Comment: $|sin (n)/n| \leq 1/n $ should help with understanding the last limit

Comment: $n+1 \ne sin(n)/n $, so that isn't pertinent.  2.5 and 2.99 are not solutions to $\frac {x^2+5}{2x}=x $.